# HoloEverywhere PopupMenu wrong background while scrolling

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using HoloEverywhere to create PopupMenu on 2.x devices. Everything is created just fine but when I want to scroll in the menu (even when the menu is not scrolling) the background of items are changed from gray to white and stay like that. I'm testing this on real device/emulator always with the same result. On 4.x devices everything is fine. The problem is very similar to issue with cacheColorHint in ListView. I'm using code:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mActivity, v);//mActivity=SherlockFragmentAct
mActivity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
//popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, popupMenu.getMenu();//same result
popupMenu.show();
```

I was trying to use my custom background in my Theme but with no luck. But it should be working even without custom background.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property

`android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: I had no luck with change style of items in PopupMenu, but I was thinking about this property already.